# emacs gdb *gud* "window" undisplayed/deleted after command

Tags: window, gud

(Manually moved by copy/pasting from [this Unix SE deleted question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171644/50557))

I'm debugging my [MELT monitor](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor), in relation with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (a domain specific language & meta-plugin to extend & customize the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler).

I'm using `emacs24` (24.4.1) on Debian/Sid/x86-64 with its `gdb-mode`; most often, I am typing `gdb` commands in the `*gud-monimelt*` emacs "window" (inside an emacs frame which is a toplevel window for my LXDE window manager).

I can't get rid of an annoying behavior; after every successfully typed `gdb` command (e.g. `bt`, or `print` ...) , the `*gud-monimelt*` emacs "window" is undisplayed or deleted (as if I typed <kbd>Ctrl-X 0</kbd>) and I have to type again <kbd>Ctrl-X b</kbd> `*gud` <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get it back.

FWIW, `gdb` is version 7.7.1 (but with a GDB 7.8 from Debian/Experimental the same is happenning).

I'm getting the same annoyance on every computer I'm using (and also on emacs-trunk `25.0.50.6` compiled daily from the latest emacs `.git`). My `.emacs` is quite small and has no occurrence of `gud` or of `gdb`

Do you know any setting to remove this automatic undisplay? I have several emacs frames and several emacs "windows" within my `emacs` session, and I don't want GUD to close automagically any emacs windows.

Comment: Can you add a minimal example? Just a single small C file, minimal Emacs config and sequence of actions
to reproduce the bug.

Comment: It probably would take me an hour of work, so I'll do that later (this evening). Do you know how to log every keystroke?

Comment: You could do with `edit-named-kbd-macro`, I guess. But it should not be
necessary as the sequence probably is just `gdb`, `gud-break`, `r`,
`bt`.

Comment: I am *not* using `gud-break`; I am typing commands to `gdb`